# dns problems hosting blog on own computer using wamp

Tags: curl, dns, wamp, wampserver

SO I am trying to host a blog at i.e. domain.com on my computer using wamp and running windows 8.

What I have done so far:

I configured my router to forward requests from port 80.  My router's address is 198.168.0.1, so I put that as the internal ip address with start and end ports as 80. I also have an external remote host address column that I left blank.

I created an incoming rule to allow port 80 requests on windows 8 firewall.

I changed the http.conf line: ServerName domain.com

My wan ip address is bound to domain.com

I restarted the wamp server and tried to get to domain.com through a browser and I get "could not connect."

I then tried to go to domain.com through my cell phone, and I get 502 bad gateway.

I called my ISP, and they said that I was free to accept port 80 requests.

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I can successfully ping domain.com but I can't curl domain.com. I can access my blog on localhost though. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what happens during an http request is your router accepts port 80 requests. The request for a certain web page then goes out on a different port via your router to your client. My firewall just so happened to block the outgoing response to the client. To fix this, I selectively blocked the incoming ports.

Comment: I do not get it : " I selectively blocked the outgoing ports." --> you mean unblocked ?

Comment: if your router allows you to selectively block the outgoing ports, that could work too. Basically you need the correct ports to be unblocked for outgoing ports and correct ports to be blocked as to prevent any security breaches.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on NAT, your problem is the port forwarding.

The local IP of your computer, the computer you want to forward port `80` request to isn't `192.168.0.1`, that is the local address of your router. There is probably a status page on your router that shows connections and will show the IP your computer is connected as, you could also run `ipconfig /all` on the command line [as described here](http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/windowsnetworkin1/ht/findaddrwinxp.htm) to find your local IP. It will probably be of the format `192.168.0.__`, but not `192.168.0.1`. Once you get that set, requests directed to your domain name should get through to your computer.